Running notebooks from one workspace to process data from lakehouses in different workspaces in MS Fabric
I have 3 workspaces in MS Fabric. Workspace A and Workspace B each contain 2 lakehouses. Workspace C, however, only contains 6 notebooks—NB2 and NB4 are for processing data from lakehouses in A, and NB3 and NB5 are for lakehouses in B. I’ve added the corresponding lakehouses to each notebook.
Notebook 1 runs NB2 and NB3 using mssparkutils.notebook.runMultiple(), and NB3 and NB5 are used to create dynamic batches to process the tables. For running the batches, we again use mssparkutils.notebook.runMultiple() in NB2 and NB3. I’ve added all the lakehouses in NB1, making a lakehouse from A the default.
The issue I’m facing is that when I run NB1, it processes data only for the lakehouses in A, but it’s unable to access the tables in the lakehouses from B.
The error message is:
"Table name: sales [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view lhb1.sales cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog. If you did not qualify the name with a schema, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct schema and catalog. To tolerate the error on drop, use DROP VIEW IF EXISTS or DROP TABLE IF EXISTS."
My question is:
Why are we getting this error when the lakehouses are already attached to the corresponding notebooks (NB3 and NB5)? I guess that since the default lakehouse for NB1 is from A, it’s unable to locate the lakehouses from B. Is it possible to change the default lakehouse dynamically when processing NB3 and NB5, so that it uses one of the lakehouses from B?
I’d really appreciate your help and suggestions.
I have tried to change the default lakehouses using some configurations but unable to adjust.

Have you considered using mssparkutils.lakehouse.get to get the id of the "remote" lakehouse and then building the path "abfss://... to reach the data in those lakehouses?

Thanks, @Andrea, I have tried "abfss://..."  it works fine with the dataframe, but when I try to use some SQL it shows an error. I think, due to the unavailability of the corresponding Hive Metastore it shows the error. Would you kindly suggest any workaround?

Which kind of SQL statements do you need to perform on your data? Just select statements or other ones?

I want to take count of the whole table ( which is a delta table). I am worried about taking the dataframe count after reading the table, since it takes time. so I want to use SQL, like spark.sql(f"select count(*) from {table}").
